# How to export log files from Travis CI to GitHUB?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI.org (Public repo) to execute my Builds and log is printing on Travis Home Page (Log File). I want to extract the log file/ send the log file to Git HUB or to any other external open source tool to access it.

Could you please let us know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? All logs are kept forever on TravisCI's S3 servers anyway

Comment: I want to send the log file to Developers incase of a build failure. Could you please tell me how to get the logs from S3 Server.

Comment: Open a job, in the upper-right corner, there's a "Raw log button/link. See where that takes you.

Comment: If you want to notify developers, have a look at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/ instead.

Comment: We are using Docker.. So, in case of a build failure all docker container logs files are storing in /var/log/docker folder. I want to push these log files to a repository in Git Hub.  Earlier I have used S3 but the requirement is changed now, and asking to upload log files into GitHub. Any Inputs are highly appreciate.

Comment: I find the question interesting because the files I want to transfer are actually images (visual regression testing).
I am actually lurking for a solution using https://transfer.sh

Comment: was there ever a solution to this? the only answer mentions "artifacts" not logs. We are having Travis run an IaC build and don't want to use their S3 buckets.

Answer (score 3):

We can deploy build artifacts to `S3` : Paste the below code in .travis.yml file if you are using github and S3.

```
after_failure:

addons:
  artifacts:
    paths:
       - $(git ls-files -o | tr "\n" ":")

deploy:

- provider: s3
- access_key_id: $ARTIFACTS_KEY
- secret_access_key: $ARTIFACTS_SECRET
- bucket: $ARTIFACTS_BUCKET
- skip_cleanup: true
- acl: public_read
```

Also, if you want to send it free open source tool, you can use chunk.io. Place the below code in a shell script and call this from after_failure section from .travis.yml file:

```
cd path/to/directory/where/untracked files store/

count=$(git ls-files -o | wc -l)

git ls-files -o

echo ">>>>>>>>> CONTAINERS LOG FILES <<<<<<<<<<<<"

for (( i=1; i<"$count";i++ ))

do

file=$(echo $(git ls-files -o | sed "${i}q;d"))

echo "$file"

cat $file | curl -sT - chunk.io

done

echo " >>>>> testsummary log file <<<< "

cat testsummary.log | curl -sT - chunk.io
```

Comment: where in the terminal output on travis can I see the correct path for `cd path/to/directory/where/untracked files store/`

Comment: Benjamin, it's `~/build/{org}/{repo}` -- yes this is necromancing, but just for public info